# Script to Automatically Advance to the Next Page of a Paginated Post

Tags: javascript, pagination, navigation

I have a custom post type that is just a paginated post and acts as a slideshow.  How can I make it so that the reader can choose an option to have the slideshow advance automatically to the next page after some preset interval (like 10 seconds)?

Comment: This is done with javascript so what slideshow are you using.

Comment: It's not a slideshow in the traditional sense.  It's just a paginated custom post type. So its just paging through the different pages of the post.  So the main permalink would be `http://mysite.com/post-title/` then the second page (or slide) would be `http://mysite.com/post-title/2/`

Comment: Hey @matt, just curious it my answer helped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi **@matt:**

To achieve what you are asking you need to add some code to queue up a Javascript file and then the Javascript file itself.

You can put the code that follows in your theme's `functions.php` file. You'll note it uses `is_admin()` to avoid loading the Javascript code in your `/wp-admin/` console; you should also add a criteria to avoid loaded it except on the pages where you need *(however I wasn't sure how to limit it since your question didn't explain enough specifics to do so):*

```
add_action('init','action_init_page_auto_advance');
function action_init_page_auto_advance() {
  if (!is_admin()) { // Make this if() limited to just the pages you need.
    $ss_url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('page-auto-advance', 
      "{$ss_url}/js/page-auto-advance.js",
      array("jquery")
    );
  }
}
```

The prior code loads a file called `page-auto-advance.js` that you'll place in a subdirectory of your theme named `/js/` and here's that file. Note it assumes you have *"next"* links on your site in the format of `<a rel="next" href="...">...</a>`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var href = $("a[rel='next']").attr("href");
  if (href!=undefined)
    setTimeout('window.location.href = jQuery("a[rel=\'next\']").attr("href");',5000);
});
```

The prior Javascript will advance the page every five seconds *(5000 = 5 x 1000 milliseconds)* if it finds a link with a `rel="next"` on the page.

One thing to be aware of is you might find that it advances when you don't want it to but with this code hopefully you'll have a starting point that will let you fine-tune it.

Comment: Sorry about that I got behind with the holidays and then this got put on hold.  I still haven't gotten it to work but your code looks good and should get me to where I need to be.

Comment: @matt - What's it not doing?